# Building a query to search registers in date results in "Incorrect syntax near '='"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find all the recorded on a specific date, my date column is of type `datetime`.

I can't understand why it's giving me this error

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Clientes
WHERE registrado = CONVERT(DATE,registrado) = '2022-10-20'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: `WHERE registrado = CONVERT(DATE,registrado) = '2022-10-20'` isn't valid syntax. SQL Server doesn't support boolean expression with 2 (or more) comparison operations. You would have to write `registrado = CONVERT(DATE,registrado) AND CONVERT(DATE,registrado) = '2022-10-20'` Though that could just then be abbreviated to `registrado = '2022-10-20'` in this case.

Comment: If you want rows on a specific date, regardless of time, however, then use a date range: `registrado >= '20221020' AND registrado < '20221021'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try too much "="

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Clientes
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,registrado) = '2022-10-20'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

To be honest I prefer the use of "CAST" instead of "CONVERT"

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Clientes
WHERE CAST(registrado AS DATE) = '2022-10-20'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Why prefer CAST over CONVERT? Sometimes you _need_ convert, e.g. imagine the source is a string in some regional format like d/m/y, you want convert with 103 instead of CAST which will make a default assumption and perhaps get it wrong.

Comment: Why perfer `CAST` or `CONVERT` when you you should be using a date range and then not change the data type (of the column) at all, @RhythmWasaLurker.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I wasn't talking about _the solution_ (I agree with you that there is no need for either _here_), just the general "I like CAST better" when CONVERT has other obvious benefits. Really you should make your comment an answer, since that is a much better approach.

Comment: (And [here's why](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/262544).)